# Does Bundle ID affect search results

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I have made an app for a client which has been in TestFlight for a while. Now they want to release the app under a different name so it won't pop up when their customers look for the company's name on the App store.

I have no problem editing the app name and store page name, however I am wondering: The bundle id still contains the company name, will the app still pop up in the app store if someone searches for that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up adding the app to the store. Which answered my question: No it does not.